# How to fix incorrect permissions when installing Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, permissions

I've just installed Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu 13.04 but i have a problem in starting the server.

I've installed Tomcat 7 by the command:

```
tar -xzpf ./apache-tomcat-7.0.26.tar.gz -C /chemin_vers_dossier_d_installation/
```

and to start the server :

```
 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/catalina.sh run
```

but i had this error message:

```
run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/fakarovic/jdk1.6.0_45/
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/conf/server.xml]
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Permissions incorrect, read permission is not allowed on the file.
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/conf/server.xml]
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Permissions incorrect, read permission is not allowed on the file.
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

NB: I already defined the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: This is problem related to file permissions. Please check for file permissions,

Comment: how ?? can u explain more ??

Comment: Can you provide me the file permissions for your tomcat installation directory

Comment: that's wont be necessary , I've changed the permissions and it works thank u So much

Comment: Be in contact... for further queries......

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, following `chmod` should fix the problem for tomcat 6 (assuming you have a tomcat6 user; it's probably the same in case of tomcat7):
`chown -RLc tomcat6:tomcat6 /var/lib/tomcat6/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem related to file permissions in linux. Check your file permission of tomcat installation directory, change it then it will work.

Becauase see this line of the log

```
May 10, 2013 9:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Permissions incorrect, read permission is not allowed on the file.
```

**The excpetion is itself shouting that I have a file permission problem.**

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding what to change? Just changing the permissions to anything probably won't help. I encountered the issue after an update and it would be helpful to know what the permissions should be set to.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has strengthened the security requirements at file system level, that's why if you are upgrading from an earlier version, you will have this problem.

From: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html

> File permissions should also be suitably restricted. Taking the Tomcat instances at the ASF as an example (where auto-deployment is disabled and web applications are deployed as exploded directories), the standard configuration is to have all Tomcat files owned by root with group Tomcat and whilst owner has read/write privileges, group only has read and world has no permissions.

Means you have to restrict the *others* access permissions to tomcat's directories. Specially $TOMCAT_HOME/conf. 
That's why you are getting the error, because there's more access that minimum required for Tomcat to start.

Long story short, restrict Tomcat directory access to only the user running the process.

> The exceptions are the logs, temp and work directory that are owned by the Tomcat user rather than root.

Answer (score 0):

An option is the following :

```
sudo chgrp -R <user> <directory_server.xml>
```

For example :

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39
```

Where :

- `chgrp -R` is the assignment of permits
- `tomcat` is the user
- `/opt/tomcat` is the directory where is it `server.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps for Windows users

- Right-click on the Tomcat directory and choose properties
- Under `Security tab`, make sure the user permissions are assigned with full-control
- Click on Advanced button.
- In the `Advanced Security Settings` pop-up, click on Add button and add user by `selecting the principal`